# Chrome Extension to submit a form automatically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, submit

I'm new to building chrome extension and I'm trying to create one that will automatically select a size of an item and then submit the form.  I have the size selection working correctly, but it's not submitting the form.  I tried to use the click() function to click the button, but it's not working either.

Below is the button html coding from the form:

```
<form action="http://*************HRtbA,,/product/102374/" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form">
<button type="button" data-track-event="Product Page - Add to Cart" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)">`
```

Here is my code:

```
function fRun()
{
    // Select size option.
    var sizesList=document.getElementsByName("super_attribute[138]")[0];
    for(var i=0; i<sizesList.length; i++)
    {
        if(sizesList.options[i].text.trim() == size_i_want)
        {
            sizesList.selectedIndex = i;
            var input = document.getElementsByClassName("button btn-cart");
            input.click();
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can't you just call the function instead of using `input.click()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements, not a single element so you will need to index your input variable to get the actual element you want.

```
input[0].click();
```

Comment: Thank you.  That worked.  Like I said, I'm fairly new to this.  Appreciate it.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept, I'll finally break the 200-rep barrier!